# My theme is not translated

Tags: themes, translation

I have translated the po file and uploaded the mo and po files in the languages folder with the language code file name. But translation is not loading
Here is the function file code:

```
if( is_dir( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' ) ) {
    load_theme_textdomain('adifier', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages');
} else{
    load_theme_textdomain('adifier', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your code inside the after_setup_theme action hook?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put your function inside `after_setup_theme` action hook

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'load_translation' );

function load_translation() {
    if( is_dir( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' ) ) {
        load_theme_textdomain('adifier', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages');
} else {
    load_theme_textdomain('adifier', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
}
```

Also, you have to make sure your theme domain is matched with the translated file.
For an easier method, I'd recommend you to use `Loco Translate`, with that plugin you can translate for themes nor plugins directly from wp-admin

[Loco Translate Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/)

Answer (score 0):

Salam,
I had the same problem but I solved it,
You should change the name of the file as you have in wordpress/wp-content-language
For exemple me I had just : 'ar.po' not 'ar-Ma.po'